# ESP-32 with tft display

Tags: adafruit, tft

I recently got a Adafruit TFT screen and an ESP-32 development kit. I was trying to interface these two the pin connections I used areas follows:

```
TFT   |   ESP-32
------+----------
3V3   |   Vcc
Gnd   |   Gnd
MOSI  |   GPIO19
SCK   |   GPIO18
CS    |   GPIO5
D/C   |   GPIO16
RST   |   GPIO 17
```

I used this library: https://github.com/MartyMacGyver/ESP32_Adafruit_ILI9341

The SPI library used was the one that comes while installing Arduino support for ESP-32.

The code compiles and uploads without any error/ warning but the TFT screen does not show any response (except powering up).

This is the code I used for testing:

```cpp
//#include <Adafruit_ST7735.h>

#include<Adafruit_ILI9341.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include "SPI.h"


#define TFT_CS     5
#define TFT_RST    17
#define TFT_DC     16

// Use hardware SPI (on Uno, #13, #12, #11) and the above for CS/DC
//Adafruit_ILI9341 tft = Adafruit_ILI9341(TFT_CS, TFT_DC);
// If using the breakout, change pins as desired
Adafruit_ILI9341 tft = Adafruit_ILI9341(TFT_CS ,TFT_DC, 23, 18, TFT_RST);


void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("In the setup.");
    //tft.initR(INITR_BLACKTAB);
    unsigned long t=micros();
    tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_RED);
    Serial.println(micros()-t);
}

void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

The code compiles and uploads without any error/warning but the TFT screen does not show any response (except powering up).

NOTE: The library works fine with Arduino Mega and TFT display.

Comment: MOSI and SCK both on GPIO19...?

Comment: I have now corrected the discription of connections sck is at pin 18 not 19.

Comment: Why have you commented out the TFT initialisation function?

Comment: That function works only wit h tft shield. I am using a separate breakout board so I have to innitialise in the format given two lines bellow.  : Adafruit_ILI9341 tft = Adafruit_ILI9341(TFT_CS ,TFT_DC, 23, 18, TFT_RST);

Comment: That instantiates the object, it doesn't initialise the TFT. I repeat: why have you commented out the **initialisation function?**

Comment: Also why tell the library MOSI is on 23 when it is on 19?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sorry for the delay, I had my exams. But I have finally solved the issue.
There were several issues:

1. MOSI should be connected to pin 23 not 19.
2. `tft.begin()` function should be in the setup to initialize the TFT. (for ILI9341)
3. The SPI library used should be the one that comes with ESP-32 support. The general SPI library for Arduino does not work with ESP-32.

Note: the ST7735 library currently does not work with ESP-32. It can be made to work by adding the following definitions given bellow to the Adafruit_ST7735.h header file.

```
    #elif defined(ESP32)
    volatile uint32_t *dataport, *clkport, *csport, *rsport;
    uint32_t  _cs, _rs, _rst, _sid, _sclk,
    datapinmask, clkpinmask, cspinmask, rspinmask,
    colstart, rowstart;
```

(add this just after the ESP8266 definitions).